# Relativpronomen »welcher« im Genitiv?

Tags: grammatical-case, pronoun

Relativpronomen gibt es in zwei Geschmacksrichtungen:

**Verwandte von »der«:**

Singular:

> Nom: der, die, das
>   Gen: dessen, deren, dessen
>   Dat: dem, der, dem
>   Akk: den, die, das

Plural:

> Nom: die
>   Gen: deren
>   Dat: denen
>   Akk: die

**Verwandte von »welcher«:**

Singular:

> Nom: welcher, welche, welches
>   Gen: **?, ?, ?**
>   Dat: welchem, welcher, welchem
>   Akk: welchen, welche, welches

Plural:

> Nom: welche
>   Gen: **?**
>   Dat: welchen
>   Akk: welche

Stehe ich nur auf der Leitung, oder gibt es für »welcher« tatsächlich keine Genitiv-Formen?

Comment: Vielleicht solltest Du noch sagen, dass es Dir nicht um das Interrogativpronomen geht (*Das Wahrzeichen welcher Stadt heißt "Fernsehturm"?*)

Comment: Wiktionary listet: "(welches), welcher, (welches)"

Comment: @Takkat: Ich denke, das habe ich mit dem ersten Wort der Überschrift und zusätzlich mit dem ersten Wort des Fragetextes bereits gesagt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Auch nach der Wiederholung im Kommentar war es Em1 anscheinend immer noch nicht klar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im Duden Band 4 – *Die Grammatik* findet man für die Relativpronomen „der, die, das“ die folgende Tabelle:

```
     │ Maskulinum    │ Femininum    │ Neutrum        │ Plural          
─────┼───────────────┼──────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────  
Nom. │ der           │ die          │ das            │ die             
Gen. │ dessen        │ deren; derer │ dessen         │ deren; derer    
     │ (veralt. des) │ (…)          │ (veralt.: des) │ (ugs.: der; …)  
Dat. │ dem           │ der          │ dem            │ denen           
Akk. │ den           │ die          │ das            │ die
```

Für die Relativpronomen „welcher, welche, welches“ gibt es eine entsprechende Tabelle mit dem Hinweis, dass die Genitivformen ersatzweise von *der, die, das* übernommen werden:

```
     │ Maskulinum   │ Femininum     │ Neutrum        │ Plural          
─────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────  
Nom. │ welcher      │ welche        │ welches        │ welche          
Gen. │ [dessen]     │ [deren]       │ [dessen]       │ [deren]          
Dat. │ welchem      │ welcher       │ welchem        │ welchen         
Akk. │ welchen      │ welche        │ welches        │ welche
```

Comment: Liegt das vielleicht daran, dass eine häufige Verwendung der "welcher"-Form die ist, um Wiederholungen vom gleichen Wort zu vermeiden. Um bei den Beispielen von Wikipedia zu bleiben: "Die Frau, welcher der Hund gehört." statt "Die Frau, der der Hund gehört." Bei den Genitivsformen unterscheiden sich die Relativpronomen von dem bestimmten Artikel sowieso, so dass eine Wiederholung ausgeschlossen ist.

Answer (score 3):

Ich glaube, es gibt tatsächlich keinen Genitiv zum Relativpronomen "welcher". An einem Beispiel wird das, hoffe ich, klar:

> Das Buch, das ich im Zug gelesen habe, hat mir gefallen.
>    Das Buch, dessen erste Seiten ich im Zug gelesen habe, hat mir nicht gefallen.
>    Das Buch, mit dem ich mich im Zug beschäftigt habe, hat mir gefallen.
>    Das Buch, durch das ich am meisten gelernt habe, ist "XYZ" von A.B.

Das korrespondiert mit

> Das Buch, welches ich im Zug gelesen habe, hat mir gefallen.
>    ???
>    Das Buch, mit welchem ich mich im Zug beschäftigt habe, hat mir gefallen.
>    Das Buch, durch welches ich am meisten gelernt habe, ist "XYZ" von A.B.

Ich wüßte nicht, was da in der Lücke stehen sollte, außer ein Ausweichen auf den Dativ:

> Das Buch, von welchem ich die ersten Seiten im Zug gelesen habe, hat mir nicht gefallen.